# Как подменить трафик программы ? Поодменить ответ GET запроса

Tags: webpack, package, взлом

Есть программа компания делает get запрос по ссылке и в зависимости от ответа пускает меня дальше или пишет ошибку. Мне надо как-то поодменить ответ что бы программа меня пустила дальше. Charlrs вроде не помогает, почему-то перехватывает запросы только в браузере.

Comment: Ответ приходит в зависимости от самого запроса. Может вам послать запрос с другими параметрами.

Comment: Как я могу послать другие параметры ? Программа не моя. Да и результата от этого не было бы никакого. Программа отправляет get запрос где сервер проверяет если ли мой пароль в ближайшее. Если есть то пишет что доступ есть и программа меня пускает. Если нету то не пускает.

Comment: Почему же ? Номер не ответить море мое?